# Suming up data based on Unique ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a ledger on Sheet 2 with a Unique ID in Column B, In Column G I have the amount of the check. I am trying to get the values of Column G to Automatically fill to the corresponding Unique ID's on Sheet 3 & 4. How would I use VLOOKUP to do this or is there a better approach?

The basis for the question is that I am trying to track when a contract is fully paid off and sometimes that can be accross multiple checks. The UID will always be connected to the contract so that will be the only constant. Seeing that we are constantly adding checks the formula gets thrown off when you use a basic =SUM formula.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Probably you should use `SUMIF` function.

Comment: *Hints*: use functions `VLOOKUP`& `SUMIFS` ;)

Comment: If there are multiple conditions to match, please check whether [SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function is helpful.